# Kendo Editor - Javascript function call on dynamically generated HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have Kendo Editor implemented in my website. Now I want to add events on dynamically generated DOM elements in kendo editor (eg. Click event on image). So how can I do that??

Basically I want to do it for making image resizable and draggable by jquery-ui inside kendo-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that only if your editor is initialized from a contentEditable element:

```
<div id="editor" contentEditable>
    Logo
    <img src="http://www.google.bg/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width=100>    
</div>
<script>
$("#editor").kendoEditor();

$("#editor img").draggable({
  containment: "parent"
});
</script>
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ELuhObe/1/edit

Comment: It is not working after I add image dynamically by kendo editor tool.

Comment: The jQuery UI draggable seems to work only with existing elements. You can try initializing a new draggable when the "select" event of the editor occurs: http://jsbin.com/ELuhObe/8/edit

Comment: What may be the reason for not working any javascript if I put KendoEditor on <TextArea> instead of <div> ??

Comment: The editor creates a separate iframe when initialized from a textarea. You need an element which isn't a textarea.

Comment: And what is the reason of putting jqueryui script reference below kendoui reference? If I put it above kendo it shows error ("object doesn't have method draggable()) ?